# Data Guard - How to fix a gap in standby database?

Tags: database, oracle, dataguard

I have a Data Guard with primary and standby database. But I have a problem, so my problem is like this. In primary if I query from v$archive_gap, I will get answer like this :

```
SQL> select * from v$archive_gap;

no rows selected
```

But if I query in standby database, I will get the answer like this :

```
    SQL> select * from v$archive_gap;
   THREAD# LOW_SEQUENCE# HIGH_SEQUENCE#
---------- ------------- --------------
         1           185            233
```

I think it is because the log has a gap, but if check with log there is no-gap (sync). So i check again in primary and standby with another query like below :

```
    SQL> select thread#, max(sequence#) "Last Standby Seq Received" from v$archived_log val, v$database 
    vdb where val.resetlogs_change# = vdb.resetlogs_change# group by thread# order by 1;
THREAD# Last Standby Seq Received
---------- -------------------------
         1                       408
```

They will show the same number of sequences, both in primary and standby. 
So i think it was sync right ?
But why my v$archive_gap in standby has many different in gap ?

Please help me

Comment: What is your 4 digits Oracle version ? Do you use Data Guard Broker ? Do you have errors in primary or standby alert logs ? Did you check if  archived logs have been applied on the standby with column `V$ARCHIVED_LOG.APPLIED` ?

Comment: Hi @pifor , my last digit Oracle version is 11.2.0.1. No I am not use data guard broker. Yes I have an error. You can check the error in this link https://safenote.co/r/5ee39f5d3ee4a7@24128174 . I check the applied archive_log the value is 'no'. I have check my archivelog, in standby i have a archivelog that in primary dont have, so I think it was a archivelog that i have been deleted because its expired. Maybe it is because of that ?

Comment: About errors, see for a possible cause https://blog.51cto.com/mckingstar/666031. If archived logs have not been applied you may need to apply them manually: see Here's an extract from MOS Doc ID 1537316.1 in https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=data-guard-physical-standby-database-redo-apply-lag-time-about-one-month

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know, select * from v$archive_gap; is meant to be run on the standby database only

Try running the following as well. Again run only on the standby.

```
  set linesize 200
  set pagesize 2000
  col name format a30
  col value format a20
  col unit format a30
  col time_computed forma a20
  col datum_time format a20
  select name, value, unit, time_computed, datum_time
  from   v$dataguard_stats
  ;
```